# Unauthorized AJAX request succeeds

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have following controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles="some_role_actual_user_is_NOT_in")
public ActionResult AJAXMethod()
{
    return Json(new { message = "server message");
}
```

and page with script:

```
function sendReq()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { somedata: "somedata" },
        url: "/Path/To/AJAXMethod",
        success: onAJAXSuccess,
        error: onAJAXError
    });
}


function onAJAXSuccess(response, status, xhr)
{
    alert("success: " + response.message);
    alert(status);
}

function onAJAXError(xhr,status,error)
{
    alert("error: " + status);
    alert(error);
}
```

When I call `sendReq` with user not in the authorized role the AJAX call still suceed - callback `onAJAXSuccess` is called, but `response.message` is undefined.

Comment: That is an expected behaviour, why don't you put the error in the controller response instead?

Comment: So does it mean that `Authorize` attribute is useless for AJAX methods?

Comment: When I think of it, isn't so that server responds with usual Login page? This would explain the success...

Comment: Are you returning the JSON message or outputting it as JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behaviour. The `success` of an AJAX call is only determined by the fact the the server responded with a 200 OK. You will need to interrogate the returned response yourself to ensure it is in the format you expect.

For example:

```
if (typeof response.message != "undefined" && response.message != "") {
   // it worked
}
else {
    // didn't work || user did not have access.
}
```